# I'm trying to upload multiple images using Multer. It all works as expected except that only one file is being uploaded (the last file selected)

Tags: node.js, ejs, admin, uuid, multer

```
<div id="item-upload">
    <p>
      <label for="image">Image</label>
      <input type="file" id="img-upload" name="image" value="uploading_img" multiple='multiple' accept="image/png,image/jpg" <% if (imageRequired) { %>required<% } %>>
    </p>
    <img id="photo-upload__preview" class="upload-preview"></img>
  </div>
```

[image]

```
const multer = require('multer');

const uuid = require('uuid').v4;

const upload = multer({
  storage: multer.diskStorage({
    destination: 'product-data/images',
    filename: function(req, file, cb) {
      cb(null, uuid() + '-' + Date.now() + file.originalname.match(/\..*$/)[0]);
    },

  })
});

const configuredMulterMiddleware = upload.array('image', );

module.exports = configuredMulterMiddleware;
```

Comment: You shouldn't include code within images. Please prove all the necessary code for a minimal reproduce example within the "```" code snippets.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.